# Cannot find libspirv-nvptx64--nvidiacl.bc when used intel clang++ to build binary for nvidia cuda GPU

Tags: nvidia, clang++, intel-oneapi, sycl

I used below command to build binary for nvidia GPU:

```
clang++ -fsycl -fsycl-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda simple-sycl-app.cpp -o simple-sycl-app-cuda
```

But got below error message:

> clang++: error: cannot find 'libspirv-nvptx64--nvidiacl.bc'; provide path to libspirv library via '-fsycl-libspirv-path', or pass '-fno-sycl-libspirv' to build without linking with libspirv

I searched in both intel oneAPI installation path and cuda toolkit path, but cannot find the `spirv-nvptx64-nvidiacl.bc`.
Anyone knows where to find `libspirv-nvptx64—nvidiacl.bc`?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to compile using the DPC++ compiler for Nvidia GPUs.

This option is not included in the oneAPI release installations from the Intel website. At the moment you will need to compile the DPC++ LLVM project with this enabled to be able to use the appropriate flag to target Nvidia devices.

You can follow [the instructions on this page](https://www.codeplay.com/solutions/oneapi/for-cuda/) to compile the project and then it explains how to use the ptx target. In the future Codeplay, the company I work for, intends to publish release binaries that include the ptx compiler option.

Comment: Hi Rod, thank you for the comment!