# gpu_selector is giving runtime error like CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND, in sycl dpc++

Tags: gpu, nvidia, intel-oneapi, sycl, dpc++

In my Ubuntu 20.04 version, we have installed intel one API dpc++. The version is; Intel(R) one API DPC++/C++ Compiler 2022.1.0 (2022.1.0.20220316)

- Where we have nvidia gpu. (Got to know by command: `nvidia-smi`) There we have `NVIDIA GeForce ... On`
- We are trying to select GPU using `gpu_selector` method. It is giving runtime error like `CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND` in dpc++. whereas `cpu_selector` is working fine.

Please check the below methods and help me. Thanks

Program:

```cpp
#include<iosteam>
#include<CL/sycl.hpp>
#include<CL/sycl/device_selector.hpp>
    
int main()
{
    cl::sycl::queue q(sycl::gpu_selector{});
    std::cout<<"Running on"<<q.get_devicee().get_info<cl::sycl::info::device::name>();
    return 0;
}
```

***2nd Method***

```cpp
    device d;
    d = device(gpu_selector());
    std::cout<<"Gpu info: "<<d.get_info<sycl::info::device::name();
```

***3rd Method***

```cpp
    sycl::device dev = sycl::gpu_selector().select_device();
    std::cout<<"GPU info: "<<dev.get_info<sycl::info::device::name>()<<std::endl;<<dev.get_info<sycl::info::device::vendor()<<std::endl;
```

output for all the methods:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::sycl::runtime_error' intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-oneapi-dpcpp-system-requirements.htmo -1 (CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Do you have also have an Intel GPU on your system? The selector probably can only find that because you do not have the built version of DPC++ with the Nvidia support. See this answer for how to use the Nvidia GPU support in DPC++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656634/cannot-find-libspirv-nvptx64-nvidiacl-bc-when-used-intel-clang-to-build-binar/70663942?noredirect=1#comment125503827_70663942

Comment: Rod’s answer is the right one. Basically you need to run Codeplay’s SYCL->CUDA compiler. 

SYCL allows to compile and run on various backend hardware, but you still need to use the right compiler. For NVIDIA hardware the right solution is Codeplay 